# How to wait for a child until it reaches CPU time timeout in c/c++?

Tags: c, fork, wait, cpu-usage

How to wait for a child until it reaches CPU time timeout?

I'm going to fork a process and wait for it exit. To be fork hang protected I'd like to limit fork execution time but CPU time not real clock time since the last may vary on system resources usage.

However looks like getrusage and times don't update children CPU time until child is exited, so the following code doesn't work:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == -1) {perror("Fork error: "); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

if (pid == 0) 
{
    /* loop working process here, should be substituted with exec() */
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <1000000000 ;i++);
        sleep(1);
    }
    _exit(0);
}

int exstat;

timespec sl;  /* sleeps before timeout check */
sl.tv_sec = 0;
sl.tv_nsec = 1000000L;

struct tms tms;

double t = 0, lim = 10; /* 10 sec timeout */
double clk_tck = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

while (t < lim && !waitpid(pid, &exstat, WNOHANG))
{
   nanosleep(&sl, NULL);
   times(&tms);
   t = (tms.tms_cutime + tms.tms_cstime) / clk_tck;
   /* FAIL: t is always zero here */
}

if (t >= lim) 
{
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    return 2; /* child timeouted */
}

int status = 0;
if (WIFEXITED(exstat)) status = WEXITSTATUS(exstat);

if (status)   return 1; /* child failed */
return 0; /* child success */
```

Is there a way to determine CPU time spent by running process (without examining /proc which looks very non-portable)?

(BTW, is there a way to terminate wail-loop immediately when child exits without waiting nanospeep cycle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change change the CPU [limit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) of the child, and it will get killed if it exceeds that limit.

```
if (pid == 0) 
{
    struct rlimit cpu_lim = {10,10}; //limit to 10 seconds
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU , &cpu_lim) == -1) {
        perror("setrlimit");
        return;
    }
```

...

With this approach you don't need to check the CPU usage in your parent process, and you can simply wait for it to die.

Comment: Works great, much better than trying to calculate CPU time, of course. Thank you a lot. Just not RLIM_CPU but RLIMIT_CPU constant I suppose.